# How do i run Ocaml function from the command line in Windows

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-toplevel

I have a question, am new to Ocaml THE functional programming. I have simple function of Ocaml which calculates a total of two numbers. Am using visual studio code. here is a sample of my function :    let cubic a b = a + b ;; 
so, how do i run my the cmd line ? 
how do i type " cubic 3 3 " such that is returns 6

```
let cubic a b = a + b ;;
```

Comment: Have you installed Ocaml? Did you run it? Did you load the file?

Comment: yes, i did stalled ocaml

Comment: i have the Ocaml terminal but i don't wanna right my code there instead use Visual Studio code and run the program from the terminal. is that possible to do ?

Comment: For that, you would have to write a cli program (which is certainly possible with Ocaml) and compile it, not just write a function.

Comment: since am knew, i used to use vs code, because when I write the code i can easily fix it when i encounter an erro... but with Ocaml you to write a cli program - which requires you to get write before you run. ( do you know if there is a better approach when writing in cli )

Comment: I'm not sure we're on the same page here. What do you actually want, a program that you can run natively in the Windows command line? Or are you just looking for a way to quickly try out your functions during development, using a (terminal-like) REPL?

Comment: am just looking for a way to quickly try out your functions during development, using a (terminal-like) REPL? --- this is what i want

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `UTop` then. It even integrates with the `OCaml` extension for vscode.

Comment: i will check out.. Thank you